# gnome lockscreen list doesn't show AD users

Tags: linux, gnome

I recendly trying upgrade from centos to rocky linux 9. after lot of testing I notice the lockscreen doesnt remember logged users (after login and log out user is not visible they must click on "not listed?"). On rocky is installed gnome gui

also,

```
ll /var/lib/AccountsService/users/
```

is empty for some reason.

Can anyone help please? Thank you very much.

Edit:
I using SSSD with realm join. Also I want say when I log in with AD user ant hit lock, user is on the lock screen but if the user is logged out it disappear

Update:
find out these messages in display manager log I think than can be issue

```
Mar 15 09:47:50 myhostname gdm-password][2437]: accountsservice: ActUserManager: user (null) has no username (uid: -1)
Mar 15 09:47:59 myhostname gdm-password][2443]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=my.username
```

Comment: sounds like you haven't 100% correctly set up your machine's AD membership. But we don't know what you did – so it's impossible to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: We using sssd with realm join for connect to domain same configuration on centos and debian works normaly only on recky I have this issue